# How to generate a pattern of lines using a text editor in different columns

Tags: vim, awk, sed

I have a text as follows:

```
a text is present
for a few lines
which I dont want 
to edit 
1 2 ab
2 3 ab
3 4 ab
4 5 ab 
5
6
7
8
```

Now I would like to generate ascending order of numbers in the second column and have the third column filled up with the string "ab" as follows.

```
a text is present
for a few lines
which I dont want 
to edit 
1 2 ab
2 3 ab
3 4 ab
4 5 ab
5 6 ab
6 7 ab
7 8 ab
8 9 ab
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're looking for:

```
$ awk '{$2=($2?$2:p[2]+1); $3=($3?$3:p[3]); split($0,p)} 1' file
1 2 ab
2 3 ab
3 4 ab
4 5 ab
5 6 ab
6 7 ab
7 8 ab
8 9 ab
```

Given your new requirement to start the above transformations at line 100:

```
awk 'NR>99{$2=($2?$2:p[2]+1); $3=($3?$3:p[3]); split($0,p)} 1' file
```

Comment: Hi, the awk command works great. However, I do have text at the start of the text file which I dont want to disturb. That is, I would like the command to work from a specific line lets say 100th line. How can I work that out?

Comment: @SaideepPavuluri Please, spill all the requirements to the question right from the beginning.

Comment: @James sorry my mistake, I was not clear about my case description. As edited in the question, I have text which I dont want to change and would like to get the output as you guys mentioned for the numbers that start after few lines.

Answer (score 1):

Another in awk:

```
$ awk 'NR>5 && NF==1{$2=1+$1;$3="ab"}1' file
a text is present
for a few lines
which I dont want 
to edit 
1 2 ab
2 3 ab
3 4 ab
4 5 ab 
5 6 ab
6 7 ab
7 8 ab
8 9 ab
```

You can control the starting record with `NR>5` or which ever line you'd like to start at.

Answer (score 0):

Using vim:

```
:g/\d\+\s*$/ %s:\v\d+ (\d+) ab\_s*\d\s*$\zs:\=printf(" %d ab",submatch(1)+1):
```

Answer (score 0):

In vim:

```
qa
  :%s/\v( \d+.+)(\n\d+)$/\1\2\1/
  w<C-a>
  @a
q
@a
```

This is a recursive macro that populates the first line that only has one column with the second and third columns from the line above, then increments the second column.